# Navigation bar not stacking properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

In the extra-small size screen, I want to have the navbar-brand and navbar-nav vertically stacked.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm bg-primary fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

But for some reason, it looks like this

[image]

How can I have the navbar-nav under the navbar-brand in an extra-small size screen?

Comment: use .collapse in items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.collapse` class and button toggler.

**UPDATE**

Just add `flex-column flex-lg-row` classes in your `nav` tag.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light flex-column flex-lg-row">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, i see your point, but i dont want to use the button and collapse approach, I only want the nav-items stacked vertically to the navbar-brand, when reducing the screen size to XS..

Comment: ohk, so please specify in question also

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the nav items to stack vertically too? I think you're looking for this...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand bg-primary fixed-top">
    <div class="container flex-column flex-sm-row">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-sm-auto mr-0">
            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://codeply.com/p/UNjoLoEnSn

Comment: Hi! :) i want the nav items vertically stacked too, yes, your proposal keeps them horizontally stacked, right?